# MySQL Hierarchical data, Recursive cte while excluding branches on condition

Tags: mysql, sql, recursion, recursive-query

I have a table `A` with this structure

```
| id | parent_id | permission_type |
```

I used the recursive cte query below to get all the children of the object with the **id 1** (in this example).

```
with recursive B (              
                id,
                parent_id,
                permission_type) as (
select          id,
                parent_id,
                permission_type
from       A
where      (id = '1')
union all
select     
                t.id,
                t.parent_id,
                t.permission_type
from        A t
inner join B
        on t.parent_id = B.id 
)select * from B;
```

The problem is that I don't want to get objects with a `permission_type = "no_permission"` nor any of their children/descendants. I want to exclude branches of the tree that descend from a node with `permission_type = "no_permission"`.

[image]

So in this case I want the output to be: (exclude the **red** branches of the tree)

```
| id | parent_id | permission_type |
====================================
| 1  |    null   |      ''         |
| 2  |    1      |      ''         |
| 3  |    2      |      ''         |
```

**Is this possible in MySQL?** If so how?

*Note:* There are other permission types, but I thought it would be unnecessary information to put here. All I care about is the ability to exclude a branch based on the permission type being "no_permission"

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH RECURSIVE 
b (id, parent_id, permission_type) AS ( SELECT id,
                                               parent_id,
                                               permission_type
                                        FROM a
                                        WHERE id = 1
                                      --  AND permission_type != "no_permission"
                                      UNION ALL
                                        SELECT a.id,
                                               a.parent_id,
                                               a.permission_type
                                        FROM a
                                        INNER JOIN b ON a.parent_id = b.id
                                        WHERE a.permission_type != "no_permission"
                                      )
SELECT * 
FROM b;
```

Comment: I tried this, but the result in this case was only the row with `id=1`. It seems like the recursion stopped when the condition was met the first time when checking the row with `id=5`

Comment: @0_jump *I tried this, but the result in this case was only the row with id=1.* Either this is according to your sample data or you have made a misprint. Fiddle added - look.